# Lazy load scoped css per component in Blazor

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-server-side

Frameworks like SvelteKit and Next.js both have support for lazily loading the css needed for a specific component. In Blazor this doesn't really exist and all scoped css gets bundled, which causes the download size to increase as you add more components.

I was looking for a way to render a component's css directly into the html instead, and came up an example:

```cs
public static class ComponentExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Apply a component's scoped css to the body of the rendered html.
    /// Removes need to load the css isolation bundle (MyApp.styles.css)
    /// </summary>
    public static RenderFragment ApplyStyles(this ComponentBase component)
    {
        return builder =>
        {
            var componentType = component.GetType();

            var ns = String.Join('.', componentType.Namespace.Split('.').Skip(1)); // remove project name from path
            // NOTE - this only works if the namespace is the same as the folder structure (component namespace has not been changed)
            // Also throws an error if the component doesn't have an associated css file
            // Also only works in Debug (see path)
            var filePath = Path.Join($"..\\obj\\Debug\\net7.0\\scopedcss", ns.Replace('.', '\\'), $"{componentType.Name}.razor.rz.scp.css");

            var cssContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            builder.OpenElement(0, "style");
            builder.AddContent(2, cssContent);
            builder.CloseElement();
        };
    }
}
```

This obviously only works on server-mode and is likely not at all performant enough, but it does apply the styles correctly.

Sample usage:

```cs
<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => currentCount++">Click me</button>

@this.ApplyStyles() @* <---  *@

@code {
    int currentCount = 0;
}
```

My question is, how could this be set up properly? Has anyone done something similar?
Looking at github for ASP.NET Core, it doesn't appear they are planning on implementing things like this into the framework itself (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37633)